# Use result of jQuery selector in Angular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to bind the expression used in a `ng-show` attribute to the result of a jQuery selector.  The reason for this is that I need to hide/show an element based on the presence of another element (`ng-view`)

The markup I have currently is

```
<div ng-view id="partialView"></div>

<div ng-show="$('#partialView').length === 0">
    <h1>MAIN CONTENT</h1>
</div>
```

and when this is rendered I get:

```
<!-- ngView: -->
<div ng-show="$('#partialView').length === 0" class="ng-hide">...</div>
```

when the `ng-view` is not provided, or

```
<div ng-view id="partialView">...</div>
<div ng-show="$('#partialView').length === 0" class="ng-hide">...</div>
```

the expression in the `ng-show` is not being evaluated (or maybe simply not re-evaluated).

My question is

Is this the correct way to bind the `ng-show` to the presence of another element in the DOM, and if it is the correct way to do it, what is wrong with my syntax that is stopping it from working?

Answer (score 1):

ng-show work with scope that you defined in controller.

you should define scope with jQuery or scope.

like

```
$scope.partialView=0 //or any thing that you want.

<div ng-show="partialView === 0" class="ng-hide">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view does not know what `$()` is, in your controller assign the jquery `$` to `$scope` element e.g. `$scope['$'] = $`

Comment: the same also applies if you want to use built in Javascript functions like `parseInt`, for them to usable in binding they must be assigned to a member of `$scope`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of @basant-rules and @martin-glennon I moved the logic into the controller, so now my controller has a function defined on it's scope:

```
var LandingPageController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.noPartialView = function () {
        return $('#partialView').length ===0;
    };
};
```

and the view looks like:

```
<div ng-view id="partialView"></div>

<div ng-show="noPartialView()">
    <h1>Main Content</h1>
</div>
```